# How to run in vim plantuml on MacOsX?

Tags: vim

Adapting the instructions at http://zbz5.net/sequence-diagrams-vim-and-plantuml, I have this in my .vimrc file on MacOSX Yosemite:

let g:plantuml_executable_script='java -jar /Users/Documents/plantuml.jar'

I have Java installed correctly as "java -version" gives a version number.

In another directory I have a uml file, diag.uml:

```
@startuml
Alice -> Bob: test
@enduml
```

When I open vim, type ":" and type g, I get a message saying "Regular expression missing from global".  How do I run the expression given by the let variable above?

Comment: :g command can't be executed separately. You need to give a pattern after it., like :g/pattern and enter to find the pattern. See this for more info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684559/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-s-commands-in-vim

Comment: so, was your problem sloved? I have the same issue with u

Comment: Your executable path looks to be missing a username. Should be something closer to `/Users/nona/Documents/plantuml.jar`. Note, you can also install via `brew install plantuml` and set your path to `/usr/local/bin/plantuml` instead of downloading the jar file

Answer (score 0):

`g:plantuml_executable_script` is the name of the variable containing the command to execute; you don't need to type its name into Vim.

Install [the plugin](https://github.com/aklt/plantuml-syntax) mentioned in the article; it'll use `g:plantuml_executable_script` to set `makeprg`, and you'll be able to process any PlantUML file by typing `:make` in Vim.