# Best Vim alternative to VSCode's Ctrl+D

Tags: vim

Lets say we are editing this totally made up JSON file:

```json
[{
  "id_4f7xg4egb": "<some_random_guid",
  // ... other fields
}, {
  "id_h34k3": "<another_id>",
  // ... different fields than prev object potentially
  "nested": {
    "id_j3h": "<nested_obj_id>",
    // ... nested obj fields
  }
},
// ...
]
```

It contains N objects (including the nested ones), and we'd like to replace the `id` value with the string coming appended to the field key itself. The result would be something like:

```json
[{
  "id": "4f7xg4egb",
  // ... other fields
}, {
  "id": "h34k3",
  // ... different fields than prev object potentially
  "nested": {
    "id": "j3h",
    // ... nested obj fields
  }
},
// ...
]
```

Now, here is what I would do in VSCode using multiple cursors:

**With VSCode** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

- Select first occurrence of `"id_` with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>x4
- Select (and create a cursor on) every occurrence of the remaining N-1 `"id_` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>x(N-1)
- Select the id string(s) following `"id_` with <kbd>→</kbd>,<kbd>←</kbd> (to deselect),  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>
- Cut them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> (yes, each cursor gets its own "clipboard")
- Delete the `_` with <kbd>Backspace</kbd>
- Select the portion we want to replace (`"<every_diff_id>"`) with <kbd>→</kbd>x4,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd>x2
- Replace the value with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get rid of the extra cursors

So we are talking about 5+N+5+2+1+8+3=**N+24=o(N)** keystrokes (taking into account the fact that, for example, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is counted only once and then held down for the rest of the N-1 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> commands).

**With the Power of Vim**

And... my question is: **How to accomplish the same result using Vim (in =< # of operations, ofc)?!** I'm a noob, one week old vimmer, and I'm loving it so far! I've been using `.` and basic macros for similar tasks, but I'm not sure what would be the most efficient way to tackle this one :(. I'd also prefer a solution NOT using plugins or involving adding some complicated mappings/functions to my .vimrc. After all, the VSCode solution is vanilla VSCode ;).

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer, but [kakoune](https://kakoune.org/) is a vim-like editor that makes extensive use of multiple cursors (as does [micro](https://micro-editor.github.io/)).

Comment: For simple text substitutions, you can just do a global substitution using :%s/old/new/g.
For more complex operations, just recording and executing a macro is probably the way to go.

Comment: If willing to use vim keybindings in vscode using the vscodevim plugin then you can edit like in vim with this feature added. More details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76358638/2826818

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By recording a macro and replaying it N times.

For example:

```
qa/"id_/e<CR>s": "<Esc>f:dt,q2@a
```

That's a total of 25 keystrokes.

Breaking it down:

- `qa`: Start recording macro `@a`.
- `/"id_/e`: Search for pattern `id_` and place cursor at the end of the pattern. The `<CR>` executes the search.
- `s`: Replace the character under the cursor (the `_`), starting insert mode. Then use `": "` as the replacement text (produces `"id": "...` and the `<Esc>` leaves insert mode.
- `f:` Move forward to the `:` after the field. `dt,`: Delete until the comma (preserving it.)
- `q`: Stop recording the macro.
- `2@a`: Execute macro `@a` two times. (If there were more id's to replace, execute it more times. Use `999@a` to execute up to 999 times, or until there's an error, whatever comes first.)

I agree that multiple cursors are pretty visual and might be easier to grasp... Vim macros can be somewhat abstract and require you to think of what these operations would do to the other positions you apply the macro to...

For this particular situation, perhaps using a `:s` command would be easier. But that's a good thing of Vim, there are often multiple ways to solve a problem and you can choose the one you prefer.

Comment: Thanks @filbranden, that's sorta what I was trying to do with a macro approach. The count before the `@a` was a great tip! I totally forgot about that one. And it makes it a fixed number of operations regardless of the N occurrences ;).

Comment: We'll, technically it's O(log N), log base 10. It's 2 keystrokes for a two digit N, three for a 3 digit N, etc. 

Answer (score 2):

I would do it in two intuitive passes and not worry about counting keystrokes or beating the wall clock.

First pass:

```
:g/id/norm f_s": "
```

- Use `:global` to execute a command on every line matching a pattern.
- The pattern is `id`.
- The command is `:normal` followed by a normal mode macro.
- The macro…

  - moves the cursor to the first `_` on the line with `f_`,
  - and substitutes it with `": "`.

See `:help :global`, `:help :normal`, `:help f`, and `:help s`.

Second pass:

```
:g//norm f:;C,
```

- Use `:global` to execute a command on every line matching a pattern.
- The pattern is the same so it can be omitted.
- The command is `:normal` followed by a normal mode macro.
- The macro…

  - moves the cursor to the first `:` on the line with `f:`,
  - then repeats the move to get to the second `:` with `;`,
  - replaces the rest of the line with a `,`.

See `:help ;` and `:help C`.

Comment: Thanks @romainl. That `:normal` after a search was mind blowing, I'll check it out! And keystrokes aren't as much a concern as just a way to measure productivity, I guess :).

Comment: Nice one! Inverting the order of operations would get you to do it in a single step: `:g/id/norm f:dt,F_s": "`. Using `:normal` with a range is amazingly powerful!

Comment: Thanks @filbranden, your inverting trick is a good idea. I generally favour intuitiveness over cleverness, though. Progressively splitting the task at hand in *n* easy to figure problems makes for a less bumpy resolution in my opinion.

Comment: @romainl Totally agreed. In my case, I guess it's professional deformation from playing too much [Vimgolf](https://www.vimgolf.com/) 

Comment: @romainl I haven't had the chance to check `:help :global` (I'm afk right now and the web version is not what one would call mobile friendly ). But I did find an article called Power of G that was pretty cool, and also this SO answer that I found to be very enlightening: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61240475/14881244

Comment: @filbranden, Vimgolf, why did you bring that to my attention? Why?!  Now all my productivity gains from switching to Vim will be offset by the time I'll waste on that one! NOOO!

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just do something like this:

```
:% s/"id_\([^"]*\)": .*,/"id": "\1"/
```

That's a global search-and-replace, matching the `"id_<something>": <stuff>,` and replacing it with `"id": "<something>"`. I think of that as a single "operation", but not sure if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks @larsks! Looks like the cleanest solution, however I accepted the one offered by @filbranden for a couple of reasons: 1) by my weird keystrokes metric, that one does better lol, 2) for a noob like myself it's easier to replay a set of steps with a macro than to figure out the correct regex replace pattern (something I need to work on), and 3) he explained how it worked xD.

Comment: My solution is similar `:%s/"id_\v([^"]*)":.*\ze,/"id": "\1"`

Answer (score 0):

Using global command becomes:

```
:g/"id/exe 'norm! f_xdt"f<vi"p'

where we find "id
normal mode
f_  .................... jump to underscore
x ...................... cut
dt" .................... deletes until " (goes to unnamed register)
f<  .................... jumps to <
vi" .................... visual select inner "
p ...................... paste default register
```

I have posted this solution but I think [filbranden's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9447571/filbranden) is better.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna make this work in your vscode, just throw this into your settings.json!

```
"vim.handleKeys": {
    "<C-d>": true
}
```

https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/2144